# Open location app from webpage link from ios browser

Tags: html, ios, geolocation, geo

I wish to make a link in my mobile website that will trigger a location based application (as waze or google maps) to open in location.

the following html code:

```
<a href="geo:32.0783087,34.81842779999999">go to location</a>
```

working great with android browsers, but not working with iphone (using safari or chrome)

How can it be done to work with iphone/ipad browsers?

Comment: Unlike Android, iOS doesn't have "intents". So can't have one link (such as above) and display a choice of locations apps. You'll need to use what @elio.d wrote.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To open google maps on ios you have to use a specific url scheme (specific for each application, if provided) for example the following will call google maps :

```
comgooglemaps://?daddr=%f,%f&saddr=%f,%f&mrsp=0&ht=it&ftr=0", contactPosition.latitude, contactPosition.longitude, myPosition.latitude, myPosition.longitude
```

and this wil open waze :

```
waze://?ll=37.331689,-122.030731&navigate=yes
```

In both cases to have this working the user, obviously, should have the apps installed.

Comment: The maps.apple.com link above this comment works on android to launch google maps.